# How do I build a Bookdown Project?

Tags: r, bookdown

I'm trying to create my first R Bookdown. I have a project created and two .RMD files created. I'm trying to build the project but all I see under the Build menu option is `Configure Build Tools`. There is no option to actually build the project. What do I need to do?

Comment: The [bookdown "get started"](https://bookdown.org/home/getting-started.html) page mentions clicking on the "Build Book" button *below* the "Build" menu, not within it. (I'm having some trouble getting it work, too, using the [`bookdown-demo`](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo) repo, so it might not be just you.)

Comment: Clarification: it's the "Build" pane in the upper-right, that's where you should be looking. Using `bookdown-0.3.1` and RStudio-1.0.44, I see "Build Website" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. At the moment I render the book with this code:

```
bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd")
```

That generate a *.Rmd file with all chapters and then I Knit this file.

---update---

In my case, in Win10, besides installing `bookdown` ,if I install `rmarkdown` package, appear a Build tab-->with `Build book` button in the upper right window, next to History and Environment tabs.

But before you have to select menu `Tools`-->`Project Options`-->`Build Tools`, and change Project build tools to `Website` from whatever you had (Makefile...or other)

Answer (score 1):

I also had to change Project Options --> Sweave --> Typeset LaTeX into PDF using: XeLaTeX. Previously I had pdfLaTeX selected. Changing into XeLaTeX made the button Build Book show correctly.